# testing for main effect on accuracy rates

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, jasp

I conducted an epxeriment with:

- 32 subjects
- 1 condition (Difficulty) with 4 levels (A, B, C, D)

And I collected accuracy rates for each trial (1 = correct, 0 = wrong).

I would like to analyze these data, but I'm aware that a classical ANOVA is not suitable, for example following this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2613284/).

Therefore, I tried to use a Generalized Linear Mixed Models (GLLM) with a binomial link (logit), within the software JASP.

So I made a model with:

- my dependent variable (1 or 0 for each trial)
- my condition as fixed effect variable
- and as random effects grouping factors the subjects

Is this procedure correct?

I also tried using the lme4 function in R, but I do not get comparable results.

---

Update

This is the code I used in R.

```
model <- glmer(accuracy  ~ difficulty + (1|participant),  data=my_data, family="binomial")
```

Concerning, estimation methods, I know that JASP uses a maximum likelihood fit. R should use a maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation).

Comparing R and JASP fit statistics are the same (e.g., AIC, BIC, log. likelihood, deviance). What changes is the fixed effects estimates.

Comment: Yes, this seems generally correct. (+1) But there are some points to clarify: 1. Do they use similar estimation methods? 2. Is the reference level (`A`  I suppose) common? 3. Is the encoding just factor encoding or ordinal (i.e. `A<B<C<D`) and is this encoding used by both routines in the same way? 4. Can you please share your code in R?

Comment: @usεr11852 I updated the question answering (1) and (4). Concerning questions (2) and (3) I'm not sure. I have to check, how do I check (3)?

Comment: Thanks, for the update. When using `factor()` we set `order = TRUE` and then have the levels. I don't know JASP at all, sorry. Also, just checking are the results "very different" or well-within reasonable error bounds, e.g. $\beta_1^{\text{lme4}} = 0.1$, $\beta_1^{\text{JASP}} = -0.1$, but the standard error is $15$ or something. Also check if using more points during the integration in `glmer` helps (`nAGQ = 8` for example - watch it, computation time might explode, I would go 2-4-8-etc.).